# Dynamics365 Operations: Where to supply the application Id for Recurring Integrations

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-365-operations

I have been following this article for recurring integration to export entities from FnO to my **NodeJs application.**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/data-entities/recurring-integrations?toc=/fin-and-ops/toc.json

I have already registered the app in AAD and performed oAuth properly. I am also able to access the data entities through oData RESTing.

But I want to access the data incrementally over a specified interval, for which I setup the recurring integration job.

The job is running fine, but when I try to dequeue the file through the export API provided in this link, it gives an error saying the Application ID was not claimed.

I don't know how to provide the Application ID since it is a GET request.

`https://<base URL>/api/connector/dequeue/<activity ID>`

Should it be as a query param or something else?
Please help.

See the screenshot for error.

[image]

Comment: Please refer https://github.com/Microsoft/Dynamics-AX-Integration

Comment: @PradeepMuttikulangaraVasu but that is sample of an integration with Logic App. I got referred to it all the time, so I tried looking at the code inside for the keywords "dequeue" and "application Id" to get an idea of how to fetch it from a curl request, but could find nothing.

Comment: They have sample app in DIXF samples https://github.com/Microsoft/Dynamics-AX-Integration/tree/master/DIXFSamples/RecurringIntegrationApp

Comment: @PradeepMuttikulangaraVasu I know, but that's a C# application. I am developing a NodeJS application on Linux. I have to learn to make it work with cURL requests

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the Application ID when you set up the recurring data job. You can check that it is set on the **Manage scheduled data jobs** page, in the **Manage authorisation policy** section. Make sure that Enabled is checked for your Application ID.

The other thing is to make sure that you have set up the AAD application for your D365 instance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/data-entities/data-management-api?toc=/fin-and-ops/toc.json#authorization

The instructions to do this are:

> 1. In Finance and Operations, go to **System administration > Setup >
>      Azure Active Directory applications**.
> 2. Select **New**.
> 3. Fill in the fields for the new record:
>
>    - In the **Client Id** field, enter the application ID that you registered in Azure AD.
>    - In the **Name** field, enter a name for the application.
>    - In the **User ID** field, select an appropriate service account user ID. For this example, we have selected the **Admin** user. However, as a
>        better practice, you should provision a dedicated service account that
>        has the correct permissions for the operations that must be performed.
> 4. When you've finished, select **Save**.
>
> You've now finished setting up the prerequisites. After the external
>   application retrieves an Azure AD authentication token, it should now
>   be able to use the token in an authorization HTTP header to make
>   subsequent service calls via OData or SOAP, for example.

Copied from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/data-entities/services-home-page?toc=/fin-and-ops/toc.json#register-your-external-application-in-finance-and-operations